# Spring roo only works if run by root

Tags: linux, spring-roo

I have installed spring roo version 1.2.3.RELEASE on Ubuntu Linux 12.04 using these instructions: http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/intro.html#intro-installation

I then create an empry directory and try to start roo as instructed in the tutorial:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html#beginning-step-1

But I get this error:

> java.lang.Exception: Unable to create bundle cache lock file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/roo/cache/cache.lock (Permission denied)

And indeed my user does not have permission to write to this file, it is owned by root as expected and if I run `sudo roo` everything seems to work. Does the installation instructions miss some vital part about permissions? Not knowing that much about roo yet, I would prefer not running it as root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just give your user (or group) write access to the roo dir (and sub dirs)?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you install Roo in a path that you're allowed to use? For instance, in your home: ~/Applications/spring-roo-1.2.3.RELEASE

Comment: Sure, that will work. But no other program I have is installed that way. I just like to keep things consistent.